# Node.js / Socket Chat - Userlist

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have been following a tutorial and a github (https://github.com/mmukhin/psitsmike_example_2) on how to make a multi room simple chat app. I'm fairly new to this.

I am trying to modify it to list the usernames in the right hand side under the room list. But it's not working, it doesn't seem to be throwing any errors though?

I have done the following:

index.html

I have added the following code to the original:

```
<div id="roomusers"></div>
```

and

```
 socket.on('updateroomusers', function(roomusers) {
    $("#roomusers").empty();
    $.each(roomusers, function (key, value) {
        $('#roomusers').append('’+value+”);
    });
 });
```

This is the original

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

        // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
            socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
        });

        // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
        socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
            $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + '> </b> ' + data + '<br>');
        });

        // listener, whenever the server emits 'updaterooms', this updates the room the client is in
        socket.on('updaterooms', function(rooms, current_room) {
            $('#rooms').empty();
            $.each(rooms, function(key, value) {
                if(value == current_room){
                    $('#rooms').append('<div>' + value + '</div>');
                }
                else {
                    $('#rooms').append('<div><a href="#" onclick="switchRoom(\''+value+'\')">' + value + '</a></div>');
                }
            });
        });

        function switchRoom(room){
            socket.emit('switchRoom', room);
        }



        // on load of page
        $(function(){
            // when the client clicks SEND
            $('#datasend').click( function() {
                var message = $('#data').val();
                $('#data').val('');
                // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
                socket.emit('sendchat', message);
            });

            // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
            $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    $(this).blur();
                    $('#datasend').focus().click();
                }
            });
        });

    socket.on('updateroomusers', function(roomusers) {
        $("#roomusers").empty();
        $.each(roomusers, function (key, value) {
            $('#roomusers').append('’+value+”);
        });
    });

    </script>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
        <b>ROOMS</b>
        <div id="rooms"></div>
        <b>USERS</b>
        <div id="roomusers"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
        <div id="conversation"></div>
        <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
        <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
    </div>
```

And the app.js (everything between the comments

> /////////**** Userlist Start ***********///////

and

> /////////**** Userlist End***********/////// is code I added

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

// rooms which are currently available in chat
var rooms = ['room1','room2','room3'];



io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // store the room name in the socket session for this client
        socket.room = 'room1';
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // send client to room 1
        socket.join('room1');
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to room1');
        // echo to room 1 that a person has connected to their room
        socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected to this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, 'room1');

        /////////**** Userlist Start ***********///////
        // get all the clients in ‘room1′
        var clients = io.sockets.clients('room1');
        // loop through clients in ‘room1′ and add their usernames to the roomusers array
        for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
            roomusers[roomusers.length] = clients[i].username;
        /////////**** Userlist End ***********///////
        }
// broadcast to everyone in room 1 the usernames of the clients connected.
        io.sockets.to('room1').emit('updateroomusers',roomusers);
    });

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
        socket.leave(socket.room);
        socket.join(newroom);
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to '+ newroom);
        // sent message to OLD room
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has left this room');
        // update socket session room title
        socket.room = newroom;
        socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has joined this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
    });



    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont know if it will help, but there are some weird quotes on the line `$('#roomusers').append('’+value+”);`
Looks like you have quotes on the right side and an apostrophe on the left..

Comment: That helped! but I think the code maybe a tad wrong too. Thanks for spotting that

Comment: your global variable `roomusers` in your `app.js` is not defined.

Comment: I tried that too and no luck :(

Comment: then you might to verify whether the data is correctly received by your client and correctly sent by your server.

Comment: Thanks, will look in to it